# How to use Multipe array value in foreach function - codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays

Here i have 3 Arrays

```
$productid= $this->input->post('productid'); 
$actualPrice= $this->input->post('actualPrice');
$quantity= $this->input->post('quantity'); 
foreach($productid as $P){
echo $p ;
}
```

Inside the loop, I need the respective quantity and actual price of the product, and I don't want to use for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer correctly you need to provide the data strucrure of your arrays.

An index based solution is not safe if products are not stored in the same order in each arrays:

```
foreach($productid as $index => $id) {
    echo 'Product ID = ' . $id . PHP_EOL .
         'Product actual price = ' . $actualPrice[$index] . PHP_EOL .
         'Product quantity = ' . $quantity[$index] . PHP_EOL;
}
```